# When should I set useCapture to false in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I've seen some tutorials and articles using addEventListener and the vast majority of time `useCapture` is set to false.

Must I set `useCapture` to false when I use addEventListener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to attach handlers to events: event capturing and event bubbling.  They're two slightly different ways of handling events, and there isn't a "right" answer: in most cases you could use either one.  But, that being said, event bubbling is the much more popular approach, which is why `useCapture` is almost always specified as false in examples.

With modern browsers, `useCapture` is optional and defaults to `false` anyways, but for compatibility with older browsers, it's often specified explicitly anyways.

You can read about the difference between capturing and bubbling here:
[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)